# Getting java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry exception

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, androiddesignsupport

I am trying to use design support library. Gradle dependencies are as follows

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

But when I trying to run app getting following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

  > Execution failed for task ':restoAdminApp:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
  >   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/recyclerview/BuildConfig.class

But when I use `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`
then it works fine.
But getting another runtime exception as follow

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to use gradlew clean and to clean the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer.Its transitive dependency problem.I have one module dependency which contain **recyclerview-v7** .

**Design support** library  also contains the **recyclerview-v7** dependency.
So it gives `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/recyclerview/BuildConfig.class` error.

I exclude the recyclerview dependency from **Design support library** as-

```
compile ('com.android.support:design:23.2.0'){
    exclude group:'com.android.support', module:'recyclerview-v7'
```

}

and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

also         `multiDexEnabled true`
clean and run project

Comment: Why should it resolve the issue? You are just adding another dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
./gradlew clean
```

The block of dependencies is correct:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
}
```